# find all directories (except `encoded`) in the working dir then delete all of them

Tags: shell-script, find, rm

I am trying to test this scenario, I have these files

```
/encoded
encode <~~~ a bash script
/dir1
/dir2
.../dir2-sub
test.meta
```

what I wish is, for `find` to search for all directories in our current (except) encoded, then delete all of them

I ended up using this script:

`find . -name encoded -prune -o -maxdepth 10 ! -name 'encode*' ! -name '.*' | xargs rm -rf`

what I believe it would do is, mark the folder `encoded` then `-prune` it, so it would ignore it, right?
then for any other, which does not have extension(which makes sure all of them are dir) delete it via `rm`

but the problem is... I also have a bash script without extension name, so it ended up getting deleted

what i wish is my bashscript to end up from the structure above to exactly like this one (keeping all non-dir intact, don't touch /encoded folder and its contents, and don't delete encode bash script)

```
/encoded
encode <~~~ a bash script
test.meta
```

how can I get the result above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to recursively enumerate directories to delete them with `rm -rf`; you can simply list the top-level directories you want to delete. To determine whether a directory entry is a directory rather than a file, you can use `find`'s `-type d` test; using `.` isn't a good indicator.

The following should work for you:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name encoded -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

This starts from all the entries in the current directory (to avoid listing `.`), drops anything whose name is `encoded`, and keeps only directories; it outputs the result using a null as delimiter, and feeds the result into `xargs` to give to `rm -rf`. Before running this variant, try

```
find * -maxdepth 0 ! -name encoded -type d
```

to see if the output matches what you expect.

`-prune` doesn't ignore its match, it avoids descending into it; so in your example, `encoded` is still listed, and then filtered by the `-name` test.

Comment: I hope I can mark your answer a gazillion twice, thank you very much for your in depth explanation. You're the best bro!